# How to start a charity project making use of college students as cram school teachers for orphans in lower levels of education?

Tags: project-team, scheduling, process, small-projects

I want to start a charity project that makes use of the human capital we have here in Morocco. The targeted population of the project is orphans of the same city and i'm having thoughts about making it national in three to 4 years time.
The project Idea is to help orphans get proper education and support from the students who are evidently teacher material ! It's like a cram school that goes to orphanages to help the orphans, not the orphans going to cram school.
And of course, it's a charity . So they won't pay for it.

I want to know how to study the reliability of the project in addition to its possibility of being applied in reality?  What are some methods to judge the viability of a project prior to pitching to stakeholders?

Comment: This is too broad, and largely off-topic as it's more about how to run a non-profit than it is about project management.

Comment: Where do I ask this question then ? @CodeGnome

Comment: @Hamza Maybe look for some forums dedicated to starting not-for-profits or even a forum specifically for Moroccan Charities. This place is for Project Management methodology and practice, not for help on specific projects.

Answer (score 1):

I'll stay away from the specifics (as I don't know the first thing about charities in Morocco) but will try to steer with some of the basics:

> i want to know how to study the reliability of the project in addition to its possibility of being applyied in reality ?

This is called a Feasibility Study. You'll be able to find lots of research specifically on how to structure feasibility studies in the NFP sector. An example: https://charityvillage.com/Content.aspx?topic=campaign_feasibility_studies_taking_the_time_to_find_out_whether_the_time_is_right#.Vi1k-H4rKM8

> i want to know how to convince college students to volunteer for the project ? and how to get them commited to it ?

Should be researched and covered as part of your feasibility study.

> If I would put together a workplan of the entire project ? how do i do that ?

Your first step would be a Strategic Plan, you want something high level before you even attempt to get into the details for something on this scale that requires significant upfront investment. An example: http://www.otsmanagement.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Strategic-Planning-for-NFP-10-Step-Guide.pdf

> How to get sponsors to help with the project ?

Sponsors generally won't be interested in "an idea". Lots of people have ideas. A Feasibility Study and a Strategic Plan would be great first steps to be able to pitch to some potential sponsors and get them involved. It shows that this is more than just "an idea" and something that has passed the rigors of some serious thinking and research (and has been found to be feasible).